# Database hosting separately than project hosting

Tags: php, database, hosting

I am using two shared hosting companies, I want to install thebuggenie in one of them, but there are two different complications came across. One shared hosting has PHP 5.3 but only allows two database. Another shared hosting has PHP 5.2.x and allows 40 database. The one which provide two database is already packed, and since thebuggenie can be installed only above PHP 5.3, can I install the Project file in one hosting which allows 5.3 and database in other hosting company which allows 40 database. If so, how ?

Comment: You can do this only if "hosting company which allows 40 database" also allow external connection to databases. (Think about probable poor performance it this case)

Comment: You need to know if the one that allows 40 DB allows access to the DB Server from outside of their hosting? If so, you might need to setup the db to allow access from the IP of the hosting server, and then just point the hosting server's db connection string. but need more info to give you specifics.

Comment: Also, although unlikely to be an issue, some hosts (only encountered one) block outgoing connections, either via `php.ini` or firewall rules.  So if the PHP 5.3 host doesn't allow outgoing connections, this too could cause issues.

Comment: No, I issued the ticket to ask them too about this, they said they don't allow this for security reasons (IDK what security BTW). I use securesignup hosting, they are damn fast in replying tickets, within 5 mins, I'm surprised. BUT they are also not willing to update to PHP version 5.3 soon enough. I have to look at thebuggenie's previous version if it works in PHP 5.2. Thank you for your replied friends !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at upgradephp - http://include-once.org/p/upgradephp/ ... it's an include that you can use on 'old' versions of php, and it will provide the functionality of currently 5.3 or 5.4... so include this on you're "shared hosting has PHP 5.2.x and allows 40 database" and it will give you 5.3/5.4 functionality.

I have used it many times now of hosting services which are slow adopters to 'upgrade' php to support any new functionality.

From their site: "With 'upgrade.php' on-hand, you can use many features from newer PHP versions (up to 5.3/5.4 currently) without losing compatibility to older interpreters and outdated webserver setups. It takes care of emulating any functions (with their original names) that are missing at runtime."

Comment: Yup, been very useful on crappy hosting that some clients have had!

Comment: nice script, I was reading through it, but unfortunately it didn't help in for thebuggenie... adding extra files doesn't act normally with their install process. I am looking for some other nice free Project Management Tool with Bug/Issue tracking features.

Answer (score 0):

This is a related anwser, just to let you know that some times hosting companys provide old versions of php as "the default" version, but they have the latest one instaled also. Its activation is aviable via .htaccess  so you can include this line to activate php 5.3 in the specific folder

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
```

Comment: sorry, this didn't do trick in thebuggenie, it shows Internal server error after adding .htaccess